# Do git pull, fetch, and clone create local and remote tracking branches?

Tags: git

git clone will create a pair of local and remote tracking branches.

git fetch will only create (or update?) the remote tracking branch, and not create a local tracking one, from http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html:

> It’s important to note that when you do a fetch that brings down new remote-tracking branches, you don’t automatically have local, editable copies of them. In other words, in this case, you don’t have a new serverfix branch – you only have an origin/serverfix pointer that you can’t modify.

How about git pull? Does git pull create a pair of local and remote tracking branches, or just a remote tracking branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-are-the-differences-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: @Makoto: according to your link, is it correct that git pull create a pair of local and remote tracking branches?

Comment: No, that's probably not the case.  I thought an answer in that question went over it in a bit more detail, but I guess it didn't.  I'll supply my own answer in a bit.

Comment: BTW, for clarity, the git terminology is "local branch" (one adjective in front of "branch") and "remote-tracking branch" (another, often hyphenated, adjective in front of "branch").  The combination adjective-pair "local tracking" should probably be avoided here, although people (and documents) will say things like "local branch foo is now tracking remote-tracking branch upstream/foo", which is confusing, redundant, and redundantly-confusing :-) and hence classic git-speak...

Comment: @torek: why "The combination adjective-pair "local tracking" should probably be avoided here"? I saw the terminology from Version Control with Git by Loeliger 2ed.

Comment: I had to go look that up.  You're correct: on page 199 they define the term "local-tracking branch" to mean "a local branch that has its upstream set to a remote-tracking branch" (via `git branch --set-upstream-to` or similar).  I think this is not a good use of terminology though: setting an upstream on a local branch does not change its behavior, it just enables shortcuts (`git rebase` and `git merge` will use the upstream information).  Besides this, it's also possible to set the upstream of a local branch to another *local* branch, which messes with that notion.

Comment: @torek: they also define a local, nontracking branch on the same page, and called it a topic/development branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform `git pull`, you're generally performing `git fetch` and `git merge`, but the main caveat here is that you're **not** creating any local branches in this manner. The merge only happens with the branch you're currently pulling into.

For instance, if you were on master, and you performed `git pull origin other_branch`, you would pull in the latest version of `other_branch` from `origin`, but then you would also be merging your changes into your master branch.  This operation would not create any local branches on your system.

The general way to create a local tracking branch from remote is through the use of `git fetch` followed by `git checkout`.  If the branch exists already on your remote repository, then simply executing `git checkout new_branch` will create a local branch that will track the remote branch for you.

Comment: Thanks. is it correct that `git pull` will update the local working directory by merging, while `git fetch` doesn't and leave the local working directory intact until I run `git checkout` following `git fetch`?

Comment: Another question. After `git fetch`, is it correct that I have two options: either  run `git checkout ` to create a local tracking branch for the  remote tracking branch and check out the local tracking branch, so that I can work on the fetched commit,  or run `git merge` to merge the remote tracking branch into the current local branch?

Comment: To your first question:  `git pull` is `git fetch && git merge`, and generally that is done on a branch that is known to be tracked remotely (i.e. master).  In that effect, this operation will update the working directory.  Using `git checkout` would update the working directory, if the branch is known to be on the remote repository.  To your second question:  yes, those are your only two options in that scenario. @Tim

Comment: Thanks. In the merge step of `git pull`, Is the remote tracking branch merged into the current branch? Does the merge step modify the remote tracking branch? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502240/branches-in-git-merge-relation-with-the-current-branch-and-whether-they-are-mo