# Branches in git merge: relation with the current branch, and whether they are modified by git merge?

Tags: git

In `git merge` of branches,

- must one of the branches be the current branch (i.e. the branch pointed by HEAD?)?
- Is the current branch called the target branch, and is the other branch(es) said to be merged into the target branch?
- Is the target branch always not specified to `git merge`, i.e. do we only need to specify the non-target branch(es) to `git merge`? If yes, is it because the target branch is always the current branch?
- Does `git merge` change the target branch only, but not the other branch?

  So is it okay to merge a remote tracking branch  (said to be read-only) to the current branch, because the merge does not change the remote tracking branch? (I am reading about the merge step in `git pull`, which merges a remote tracking branch into the current branch, and I remember a remote tracking branch is read-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are right

  ```
  git merge <topic>
  ```

  This command will merge the `topic` branch to the current branch, i.e. the branch currently pointed to by HEAD
- There are no naming conventions for the current branch during merge, but yes, in this case, the topic branch is said to have merged into the current branch
- Only the branch *to be* merged can be specified. The branch *into* which the merge happens is always the current branch
- git merge changes only the current branch. Additional commits can be added to the `topic` branch and can be merged again.

EDIT:

A remote tracking branch is read-only in as much that it does not contain a working directory. So no changes(read commits) can be made directly to the remote branch. However you can always push changes to the tracking branch

So yes, it is okay to merge a remote tracking branch into the current branch. However the `git merge` in `git pull` is optional. You can set `git pull` to do a `git fetch` + `git rebase` if needed.

Comment: Thanks. About the last part. 

So is it okay to merge a remote tracking branch (said to be read-only) to the current branch, because the merge does not change the remote tracking branch? (I am reading about the merge step in git pull, which merges a remote tracking branch into the current branch, and I remember a remote tracking branch is read-only)

Comment: What do you mean by "However you can always push changes to the tracking branch"? By "the tracking branch", do you mean the current branch or the remote tracking branch?

Comment: The remote tracking branch

Comment: What do you mean by "push changes to the remote tracking branch"? Remote tracking branches are read only. Do you mean to modify the remote tracking branch?

Comment: I am confused. When I said push changes, I meant run `git push`. I am not sure what you mean by *read only*.

Comment: I guess in your "push changes to the remote tracking branch", "the remote tracking branch" should be the tracked branch in the remote repository.